# Run a very old InterLisp program

Tags: lisp

I have some proprietary data (civil engineering models) stored in binary files. There's also some InterLisp sources and a core dump file (I guess this is what Lisp compiles to ... for some reason). I'm told that program is a GUI for manipulating the models and exporting and importing the data.

I'm looking for advice on how to get the data out of the binary format. Is there an InterLisp interpreter that would work on a modern OS? If not what is my best option for porting the code to a more recent Lisp platform?

Comment: Did you try some basic googling and tools like http://algorithms.us/software/lispf4/index.html ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've gotten an Interlisp environment running on my machine using QEMU and old Debian images before (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giPnC.png)). Here are the steps:

- Download and set up a Debian 3.0r2 install in a virtual machine (or physical machine if you have an old one spare). Get the disk image from the [archives](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/archive/3.0_r2/i386/).
- Get the [LFG](http://www2.parc.com/isl/groups/nltt/medley/) software from the PARC FTP server (the link is on the page) which includes an Interlisp environment. The FTP server also has a Linux emulator called `lde` to run the image.
- Use `lde` to run the Interlisp image (`lfg.sysout` IIRC) inside the virtual machine.

This is all do-able with software that's distributed on the web. You can still find old Interlisp manual scans around too. Ideally, I would just provide a working VM image, but since it's not free software I don't want to redistribute it unofficially.

Comment: Can we get an unofficial VM image?  I jumped through a lot of hoops to install debian 3.0 on qemu, but I'm a bit lost trying to get the LFG files on the image.  internet connection doesn't seem to work inside the image

Answer (score 4):

Interlisp is either the Interlisp language (which during its lifetime had been ported to several different machines) or the extensive Interlisp-D environment from Xerox.

An Interlisp-D emulator was (is?) available commercially here:  http://top2bottom.net/medley.html

Here is a interpreter for Interlisp (the language) written in C for Linux and Windows:  http://algorithms.us/software/lispf4/index.html

Comment: LISPF4 is now at https://github.com/blakemcbride/LISPF4